# I accidentally hit "close other tabs" in Firefox, but I can't restore them over "recently closed tabs"

Tags: firefox, session, browser-tabs

I accidentally hit "close other tabs" in Firefox 7, but I can't restore them over "recently closed tabs". How can I get my tabs back?

Under "recently closed tabs" there are only the tabs I closed manually. It does not show the tabs that have been closed by "close other tabs".

Comment: Check your firefox history.

Comment: the thing about ff-history is: i cannot differ between tabs that were open or tabs that i already closed. its a bunch of sites i visited and somewhere are the sites i want, but i dont even know the sites i visited anymore. there has to be another solution. but thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Good reason to install a session manager that automatically records your sessions.

There are several available over on the Firefox Extensions website (search on sessions) to allow you to restore saved sessions, including after a failed Firefox crash recovery which is the most common way to lose everything.

Like undone backups, it won't allow you to recover what you've lost (searching site history is the only way at this point) but will help you in future recoveries.

Answer (score 2):

If you accidentally close tabs then quickly(before backup is overwritten after a minute) close firefox and rename %UserProfile%\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[RANDOM FOLDER NAME]\sessionstore.bak to sessionstore.js.Then reopen Firefox.

Or open a copy of sessionstore.bak in firedfox and use sessionrstore javascript to extract links.